# create array of array from object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have object like this

```
{2015:1.5,2016:1.5, 2017:1.5,2018:15 ,2019:1}
```

I want to create 2d array like this way

```
[[2015,1.5],[2016,1.5],..]
```

I tried from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301115/how-to-create-2d-array-from-object-key-value-par) but didn't work. how should I do?

EDIT 1:

basically I have 2 data. one consist of array of year and second consist of array of data. `[2015,2016]` and data is like `[1.5,1]`. I want to merge like `[[2015,1.5],[2106,1]]`.

Comment: Your object is wrong.

Comment: Please provide Your code, current result and desired result.

Comment: I have got it from backend

Comment: This is not a valid object. Commas are missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a string, you can split it twice:

```js
var s = "2015:1.5 2016:1.5 2017:1.5 2018:15 2019:1";

console.log(
  s.split(" ").map(x => x.split(":"))
);
```

---

If you have an object, use `Object.entries` to convert it to an array:

```js
var obj = {2015:1.5, 2016:1.5, 2017:1.5, 2018:15, 2019:1};

console.log(Object.entries(obj));
```

---

```js
var year = [2015, 2016];
var data = [1.5, 1];

console.log(
  year.map((y, i) => [y, data[i]])
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `array#map`

```js
const obj = {2015:1.5, 2016:1.5, 2017:1.5, 2018:15, 2019:1};

var result = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => [key, obj[key]]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```